# How can Traversable.isEmpty calculate in O(1) whether the Traversable is empty or not based only on forEach() in Scala?

Tags: scala, traversal, scala-collections

When implementing a `Traversable` data-structure I can understand how one can implement a map / filter or even fold using a `forEach(f)` : for each element in the data-structure, `f(element)` will be called and it's then up to the `Traversable` method in question to interpret and do whatever it pleases with the sequence of `f(element)` calls it gets.

What I don't get is how is it possible to implement a `isEmpty` or a `take(3)` in O(1) or O(k) times, respectively. I've done simple tests and I've seen that isEmpty will in fact only consume the first element of the data-structure (if there's one, that is).

How can this magic be done in Scala? I've been looking at the sources but everything (still) seems quite magical to me. `isEmpty` seems to be defined as follows:

```
  def isEmpty: Boolean = {
    var result = true
    breakable {
      for (x <- this) {
        result = false
        break
      }
    }
    result
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: The `break` call is taking program execution outside the block marked with `breakable`, aborting the for loop after the first element found.

Comment: I would add that `break` throws an exception and `breakable` catches it.

Comment: @sjrd ahhhh, that makes a whole lot more sense. I was finding it odd how could this work without throwing exceptions of some sort. But doesn't that bring with it a disastrous performance penalty?

Comment: @devouredelysium It's not as bad as it seems, because exception thrown in there is actually a `ControlThrowable` which doesn't calculate stack trace, thus avoiding the most performance-heavy piece of throwing exceptions in JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make it a bit simpler (less functional):

```
def isEmpty: Boolean = {
    for (x <- this) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

If the collection is empty, `for` loop makes nothing so we have O(1). If there is some element in the collection, function returns false when iterating over the first element. This is also O(1).

The breakable implements almost same logic.